# deduce two different known type variables in different parameter packs within a variadic function

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I have the following code:

```
template <typename... Type1, typename... Type2>
void foo(const Type1&&... t1, Type2&&... t2)
{
    int len = sizeof...(Type1);
    cout << len << endl;
    int len1 = sizeof...(Type2);
    cout << len1 << endl;
}

int main()
{
    foo(1, 2, 4.5, 5.5);

    return 0;
}
```

calling `foo()` deduces `Type1` as empty and `Type2` as `{int, int, double, double}`, while what I would like to have is `Type1` as `{int, int}` and `Type2` as `{double, double}`.Is that possible without involving `std::tuple` and just calling the `foo()` function as I have it in the above code?

***edit*:**

---

To make more clear what I want to achieve, here is an explanation. I want to create a function where the user will be able to pass an arbitrary number of two kind of type variables in even number of pairs each time. Let's say `foo(Type1 x, Type1 y, Type1 z, Type1 ..., Type2 XX, Type2 YY, Type2 ZZ, Type2 ...);` the variables of `Type1` would always be `const` references while the variables of `Type2` just references, so the function would end to have the following form: `foo(const Type1& x, const Type1& y, ..., Type2& XX, Type2& YY, ...)`. Within the function I would apply some computations using the `Type1` variables and return the corresponding result through the `Type2` variables. I know that the use of any container structure would make my life easier but, unfortunately I cannot go with that solution. So, though I am not an experienced I think that the use of a variadic function is the way to go, am I right?

Comment: how compiler know the boundary of each types ? That's is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the compiler cannot read your mind.

You can split a pack of types in half:

```
template<class...>struct types{using type=types;};

template<class lhs, class rhs>struct cat;
template<class lhs, class rhs>using cat_t=typename cat<lhs,rhs>::type;

template<class...lhs, class...rhs>
struct cat<types<lhs...>,types<rhs...>>:
  types<lhs...,rhs...>
{};

template<class types, size_t n>
struct split {
private:
  using s0 = split<types,n/2>;
  using r0 = typename s0::lhs;
  using r1 = typename s0::rhs;
  using s1 = split<r1,n-n/2>;
  using r2 = typename s1::lhs;
public:
  using lhs = cat_t<r0,r2>;
  using rhs = typename s1::rhs;
};
template<class Types>
struct split<Types, 0>{
  using lhs=types<>;
  using rhs=Types;
};
template<class T0,class...Ts>
struct split<types<T0,Ts...>,1>{
  using lhs=types<T0>;
  using rhs=types<Ts...>;
};
```

and then we use this to split the `foo` arguments into two packs:

```
template<class types>
struct foo2_t;
template<class... T0s>
struct foo2_t<types<T0s...>>{
  template<class... T1s>
  void operator()(T0s&&... t0s, T1s&&... t1s) const {
    std::cout << sizeof...(T0s) << '\n';
    std::cout << sizeof...(T1s) << '\n';
  }
};

template <class... Ts>
void foo(Ts&&... ts) {
  using s = split< types<Ts...>, sizeof...(Ts)/2 >;
  foo2_t<typename s::lhs>{}( std::forward<Ts>(ts)... );
}
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/461870260a82f4db)

If you want the compiler to do different magic (say, clump on identical types, or whatever else you had in mind), a different (yet similar) technique would work.

Comment: [This doesn't work.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aca5e705c17cd8a5)  The function parameter pack `t0s` appears in a non-deduced context, and I'm not quite sure what's supposed to happen given the special rule in [temp.deduct.call]/p1 "When a function parameter pack
appears in a non-deduced context (14.8.2.5), the type of that parameter pack is never deduced."

Comment: @T.C. huh, that is a surprise.  The `T0s` to me look like they both can be deduced; but I guess they are deduced to be two different packs.  And if I block deduction of one of them, I guess no good happens.  Tweaks didn't fix it either.  Fixed it with a function object and two packs, only one deduced at the call site (I could have just passed in both packs I suppose?)

Comment: @Yakk thanks a lot, your approach seems quite promising and definitely I will try it. To make more clear what I want to achieve, check the edit at my original post ;-).

Comment: How I can unpack now t0s and t1s as references? Check [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d16988efa6e4fa0e) the example.

Comment: @theodore you cannot have an array or vector of references.  You can have an array of `std::reference_wrapper`?  Or an array of pointers?  Note that `T1s` itself isn't a literal type: `common_type` would work, but you cannot have a common type reference to a collection of different types.   http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/230c935867aea93d does a tie instead of an array.

Comment: @Yakk thank you so much. `tie` seems to do the job I need. ;-)

Comment: @Yakk one last question regarding your example, what is the purpose of `(void)(tie_t0s);`?

Comment: @theo unused variable warning suppression.  Because I did not use it.  And -Wall and warnings as errors makes the build break.

Comment: @Yakk I see. Sorry, for all these newbie questions but I am quite new to all of this. I am really grateful to your help. Also another, thing that I noticed is that for example in [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e2f915f010142e4a) example if I use `std::tie` for different input variables, if I have created an if statement in order to deal with different sizes I am getting the following error  `"tuple_element index out of range"` or `"error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct std::tuple_element<0u, std::tuple<> >’"` do you have any idea how I can deal with it?

Comment: @theo all branches of an `if` must be valid code (types, etc).  You'll need somethimg like tag dispatching.  Not enough room in a comment to diagnose and fix.

Answer (score 0):

Try more simple way.
Take two vectors as arguments.

```
template<typename T, typename A>
void foo( std::vector<T,A> const& t1, std::vector<T,A> const& t2 ) {

//do wtever you want

}
```

Comment: Why allocate on the free store?  `std::initializer_list`

Comment: Just mention, if no need can skip it. Here for int/double we don't need it.

Comment: no: your code allocates memory on the free store.  There is plenty of need to avoid doing so needlessly.

Comment: So, this should be wt you need, fine
template<typename T>
void foo( std::vector<T> const& t1, std::vector<T> const& t2 ) {
//
}